# Union empty Dataframe with a full dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have two `Python dataframes`, I do a test before filling them, so sometime one of them is empty.

When I did Union of the two dataframes, it returns `AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'union'",)`, I tried to return the dataframe that is not empty, in this case I got a result.

Structure of my code:

```
df_result = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

Test if of the first datafarme....

Test if of the second dataframe.....

Final result:

df_result=df1.union(df2)
```

How can I do a Union of two Python dataframes, one of them being sometimes empty?

Comment: Try using `pandas.concat((df1,df2))`.

Comment: @SandeepKadapa Thank you, I'm using Spark 2

Comment: @user006 Please incorporate this information into your question and add the appropriate tag. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Mr.T Thank you, I know this information, I resume in my question because I have a Big function so it is useless to write it, I put just the essential

Comment: @user006 My main point is that you attract with your question Python/Pandas user while you seemingly want to address people who know PySpark (or whatever is relevant). An explicit mention in the question and additional tags might help you finding the right users.

Comment: @Mr.T Ok thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html?highlight=concat#pandas-concat):

```
df_out = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Answer (score 0):

if the DataFrames have the same structure, you can use `df1.append(df2)`

Comment: Always the same error AttributeError("'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'append'",)

Comment: can you show the complete script? because according to the documentation, pandas dataframes have the method `append`.

Comment: Ok, but me I'm using a Spark

Comment: i'm not sure if there is something called a `python DataFrame` - i was talking `pandas DataFrame`. Is it available in Spark too?

Comment: unfortunately no